# Im trying to launch an already installed 3rd party app from the app I created on AVD but my program in AVD wont launch 3rd party app

Tags: java, android, android-virtual-device

Im doing an appdrawer section to my Android app I am building, I am using Package Names and getLaunchIntentForPackage() to launch the 3rd party app from my phone. The function, imageview that's runs that function worked perfectly for built in apps but for some reason they wont work for downloaded apps even though I input the apps' package names correctly on AVD. I'll share what else I've done below but first I want to mention my specs/program version:

Android Studio Giraffe | 2022.3.1 Patch 2
Build #AI-223.8836.35.2231.10811636, built on September 15, 2023
Runtime version: 17.0.6+0-b2043.56-10027231 amd64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
Windows 10 10.0
GC: G1 Young Generation, G1 Old Generation
Memory: 1280M
Cores: 8
Registry:
external.system.auto.import.disabled=true
ide.text.editor.with.preview.show.floating.toolbar=false

The AVD I am using: Pixel 4 API 34 (The version that is compatible with Google Play)

My device and windows version if they're relevant:
Processor   Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-7700HQ CPU @ 2.80GHz   2.80 GHz
Graphics Card   Nvidia GTX 1060 3 GBs Laptop version
Installed RAM   8,00 GB (7,89 GB usable)
System type 64-bit operating system, x64-based processor
Edition Windows 10 Home
Version 22H2
Installed on    ‎7.‎09.‎2023
OS build    19045.3803
Experience  Windows Feature Experience Pack 1000.19053.1000.0

activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="304dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="112dp"
        android:text="Button"
        android:onClick="onClickey"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="98dp"
        android:layout_height="88dp"
        android:src="@drawable/indir"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.083"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.024" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

And MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.denemeee;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ImageView chromeview = findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        chromeview.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                onClickey(view);
            }

        });
    }
    public void onClickey (View view){
        Intent intent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.csdroid.pkg.MainActivity");
        if(intent != null){
            startActivity(intent);
        }
        else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Didn't work again :(", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES" />


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Denemeee"
        tools:targetApi="31">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

and finally buil.gradle.kts:

```
plugins {
    id("com.android.application")
}

android {
    namespace = "com.example.denemeee"
    compileSdk = 33

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "com.example.denemeee"
        minSdk = 26
        targetSdk = 33
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles(
                getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"),
                "proguard-rules.pro"
            )
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation("androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1")
    implementation("com.google.android.material:material:1.5.0")
    implementation("androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4")
    implementation("androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0")
    testImplementation("junit:junit:4.13.2")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1")
}
```

What I was expecting: I was expecting the button or/and the imageview to launch the app called "Package Names" from the app I built when I click on the imageview or/and the button.

What I've tried:

Originally I tried this on Google Chrome app as the part of my project. When it didn't work I downloaded "Package Names" app from google play to my phone and got the apk of it, built it on my AVD. I opened the app to check if I was correct and Chrome's package name was indeed "com.android.chrome", then I tried to launch the Package Names app itself from the app I built and it didn't launch as well.

Both Google Chrome and "Package Names" apps launch flawlessly when I launch them from UI by clicking on their icons at AVD. They dont crash whatsoever so the apps themselves are working fine.

When I change the package name on the function from the third party app to a system app (such as options) it worked just fine.

Then I tried to cold boot the AVD
Wipe the data of AVD
Removed the AVD completely and rebuilt it
Closed and reopened both Android Studio program and my laptop.
Tried running Android Studio as admin

Added a permission on my Android Manifest file from what I've found upon searching.

Triple checked if there's a mistake on the code.

Checked the Developer Menu of the AVD to see if there's anything stopping my app to open another 3rd party app.

Later I got a button on activity_main.xml to see if the problem is on imageview. Added an onClick function to the button and connected to the function over AcitivityMain that launches the apps.

And at the end I built an APK file of the app and sent it over my personal usage phone (Samsung S8 Edge+, Android Version: 9.0) which had the "Package Name" app downloaded inside it as well. When I launched my own app that's supposed to launch "Package Name" app it actually worked and launched the app flawlessly.

Then I came to the conclusion that this was something related to Android Studio since I have tried everything I can over AVD side.

I did try to debug it but couldnt come to a senseful conclusion plus I already knew the app was working since it worked just fine on my personal phone.

Left an image that shows the app itself is working fine on the AVD and the package name of the app Im currently trying to launch.

I wonder if this is some kind of bug on Android Stuio or is there something I am simply missing?  I've tried to find a solution on this at all over the internet for hours now.